# Is it possible to set your own white space in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, typesetting, formatting, white-space

I'm looking for a way to set my own white space in InDesign. In the same way as you can insert em-space or en-space I would like to insert a certain amount of space I've decided myself.

I.e. a white space of 20 mm or something. I want to be able to use the same white space over and over again in different places in a body text.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

There might be different ways to achieve this, but the first that comes to mind is:

- add the usual EM spaces where you need them, there's a shortcut for EM space <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> so this can be done without using the actual app menu
- then create a character style which would apply a custom horizontal scale to specific characters
- then run a find/replace, and replace EM spaces with EM spaces formatted with this character style

[image]

[image]